# In accordance with the user name query in lucene

Tags: lucene, full-text-search

I want to provide an search function on a blog website. But I want to search not only on whole documents, but also I want search on just one author's documents.
As I want use lucene to provide Full-text index,how can I do this when create index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing the author's name as a separate field would let you search for all documents containing "Lucene" with an author of "fisher", for example ("lucene author:fisher" in QueryParser syntax).